# compareSync of Bcrypt always returning false

Tags: javascript, mongodb, postman

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")

const validateUserInput = (email,password) => {
    return email && password;
}
const comparePassword = (password, hashedPassword) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashedPassword);       
}
module.exports = {              
    validateUserInput,
    comparePassword
};
```

```
const register = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {


    const {name, email, password, role} = req.body;

    const user = await User.create ({
        name, 
        email,
        password,
        role
    });
    sendJwtToClient(user,res);

})
```

```
const login = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {

    const {email, password} = req.body;
    if (!validateUserInput(email, password)) {                           
                               
        return next(new CustomError("Please check your inputs", 400));
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

    if (!comparePassword(password, user.password)) {
        return next(new CustomError("Please check your credentials", 400));
    }
    
    sendJwtToClient(user,res);

module.exports = {
    register,
    login,
    getUser
}
});
```

My intention here is to decrypt the encrypted password and compare it with the one provided by user. I am using postman to test my application. It always returns false. I almost tried everything but didn't find a solution to fix this and wanted to listen your suggestions. I am still trying to learn javascript and I already checked the other questions about this topic in stackflow.

I also want to share the screenshots of postman in order to provide a better explanation to you.

**Postman register :** https://prnt.sc/D0M__puraDME

**Postman login auth :** https://prnt.sc/gYj_RcmfV1z9

I am very new here, if I did any mistake while asking question please let me know.

**Update:**
I did what you asked and tried to use log in some places. I will post the outcome here. Still having troubles to fix this. I still need some help.

https://prnt.sc/M1JSrz-fYJHi I use console.log on password and hashedPassword in here.

https://prnt.sc/LEhiAElf0ber I used console.log on user.password and password in here.

I have to share this with image because it also contains postman actions here.

Comment: You only select the `password` field. But you are passing `user.password` to the function which is undefined. That's why it's returning false always. Try with `comparePassword(password, user)`

Comment: After register process, the password given by user become encrypted. I am trying to decrypt that already  stored password and in the login auth trying to compare with the given password again. When I do what you said. It gives this outcome. https://prnt.sc/rMqC0ULWr4_s @Eldar

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log(user)` and see what you got?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski on where exactly? under login part? I tried console.log(user) on register and it gives encrypted version of the password given by user.

Comment: Yes on login, I guess that you are not getting what you expect. Or at least try log `password` and `hashedPassword` to see if they are defined

Comment: @KonradLinkowski console.log(user.password) gives this : $2a$10$4c/a30g8UQ/PV/J0jQPQhOxtW4Otjn68yL3vQAf4RR0QdQY0esdou So that means, user.password is the hashed version of the password here. I guess comparePassword not decrypting some how. In addition to that, log hashedPassword gives this on postman:  "message": "hashedPassword is not defined"

Comment: @KonradLinkowski hashedPassword is on another js file. Maybe something happening while exporting? https://prnt.sc/0pe3EFatv0Bs

Comment: My last guess is that you have more than one user with the same email in the database

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Due to some another script, it doesn't allow me to create a user with same email. I already use a code part that restricts it.